Getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')" when using useSearchParams in Storybook file
I have the following Next.js code in a component:
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const currentPage = parseInt(searchParams.get('page') || '', 10) || 1;

I get this error in the Storybook stories:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')

The offending line is this:
const currentPage = parseInt(searchParams.get('page') || '', 10) || 1;

After reading the official Storybook docs, I tried this:
const meta: Meta<typeof ItemModal> = {
  title: 'Example/List',
  component: ItemModal,
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      appDirectory: true,
      navigation: {
        searchParams: {
          page: '1',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

Also this:
navigation: {
  segments: [
    ['page', '1'],
  ],
},

And this:
navigation: {
  segments: [['?page=1']],
},

But I'm still getting the same error.
What am I doing wrong?
Also posted here.
Update: I did console.log('seachParams:', searchParams); and it's returning null even though I did this.
This is the full component.

Are you able to post the full component you're calling useSearchParams from? The issue seems to be the useSearchParams call not being properly executed, returning null instead of the proper URLSearchParams. Even if the ?page=1 query param doesn't exist in the URL, it should never return null.

@ChristopherOka I updated the question with a link to the full component.

i think i know what's going on, it is a client hook, and it seems like it is being used in server component context

Thanks! Are userRouter and usePathname also returning null, or just useSearchParams?

@ChristopherOka Ah, useRouter and usePathname return their respective functions. Only useSearchParams is returning null...

useSearchParams hook only works with client components in next according to docs.
Try to add "use client" on top of your component.

I tried adding "use client" to the component and "use client" to the Storybook file. Same error.
